# nightwatch-cucumber keep browser open for testing?

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js

When running a single test I would like to keep the browser open after running form fills so I can debug. Is there any way to do this with nightwatch-cucumber? Thanks would be a huge help.

Comment: How does your test look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a cucumber problem its a javascript problem, and I'm not a javascript expert, but I'd suggest you try putting a breakpoint before an assertion that looks at what your browser is showing.

Normally with a Cucumber scenario you would have a THEN, that looks at the view and tests something, just put the breakpoint in there before the assertion